# how to replace question mark symbol from data set and replace with adjacent row value?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, text-processing

I am reading the .csv file using pandas and I can see there are many ? symbol in it. I want to replace all with either adjacent value?
How to achieve that? any idea please!

```
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
data.head()
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Would it be possible to provide a small example of your dataframe and data.head() output? It would be good to indicate what row/column value should replace the "?".

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
data.head()

data.replace(to_replace ="?", value ="whatever number")
```

replace the value variable's string with whatever number you would like.

Comment: Thank you Zakariah for response. I was trying to apply the rule on specific column, suppose "ColumnB" and replace it with adjacent column (like "ColumnA") value. Foe example, if the "?" symbol is at row 5 in columnB then I would like to replace it with row 5 of columnA. Is it possible?